# Not able to call mstsc.exe for RDP in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-xp

I'm using am windows xp 64 bit machine and trying to RDP into another machine. When i call mstsc i get the error "the system cant find the file specified". What am i doing wrong? The code is below

```
Process.Start("mstsc", "/v:" + txtBX.Text);
```

Comment: I don't know if you need to include .exe or not (i.e. "mstsc.exe"), but I believe the "bitness boundary" cannot be crossed. I mean, if your code is compiled as a 32-bit app, it probably can't start a 64-bit process (and vice-versa). So I would verify that the computer even has mstsc.exe, if it's 32 or 64 bit, and make sure your app is compiled to match. Just because it's 64 bit XP doesn't mean all apps are 64 bit. In fact, if I remember correctly, 64 bit XP was a mess.

Comment: Also, since you didn't provide the path to mstsc.exe, make sure it's in the PATH environment variable.

Comment: @JeffShepler Thanks!. Its was the 64 bit issue. I compiled my app as a 64 bit and also i added the full path for mstsc.exe. It's working fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was compiling my app as 32 bit. Changed it to 64bit and put the full path of mstsc.exe.